# Window type char

Tags: c++, opencv, char

I am new to coding in C++ and am currently working on an application that can clear all objects out of a picture except for the biggest one. I was looking on doing object size detection based on the bounding boxes tutorial I found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html)

I was looking into implementing a piece of code with the code that can be found in the link so I could set up the 'bounding boxes' technique with a live video feed instead of an image, but then I ran into this bit here:

```
/// Create Window
char* source_window = "Source";
namedWindow( source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imshow( source_window, src );
```

Why would you make this of the type char and not just do it like shown below?

```
Mat edges;
namedWindow("edges",1);
```

As I stated earlier im really new to coding with C++ and opencv, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no real reason - but it ensures that you can't get the name wrong by mistyping in the `imshow` call.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in treating this code as suspicious. The type of `source_window` is wrong.

It currently is defined as a pointer to `char`. Yet it is initialized with a string literal, which has type `const char[]`. While there is a conversion that converts from array `[]` to pointer `*`, there is no conversion which drops `const`.

The reason why you'd assign a name to such a constant is generally because you use the same constant in two places. Typing it twice increases the risk that you make a typo and end up with two different strings. That can be as simple as a spelling the second string "source".